Is passenger rail in Japan at least an order of magnitude safer than in the U.S. (as measured by fatalities per passenger-km)?
I've seen several statements online praising the safety of passenger rail in Japan and China compared to the US, implying that rail in the US is at least 10x less safe. For example, pedestrianobservations.com claimed in 2011 that the fatality rate in Japan was "one death per 51.4 billion passenger-km", while

US: 27.26 billion passenger-km/year (both Amtrak and commuter rail), 159 deaths over 20 years. Note the rate is more than twice that of China per capita, let alone per rail passenger. This is one death per 3.4 billion passenger-km.

But is it really true that passenger rail is an order of magnitude less safe in the US? To be specific, we can

Focus on Japan (to avoid potential concerns about the quality of reporting on on China's rail safety).
Focus on one specific metric: R = fatalities per billion passenger kilometers.
Include the number of all fatalities (e.g. level crossing users) in passenger rail accidents, not just the number of passenger fatalities.
On the other hand, the question is specifically about passenger trains, so freight train safety is explicitly out of scope (and freight train fatalities are not included in the numerator of R).

Is it true that this metric is at least 10 times higher in the U.S. than in Japan?
Clarification regarding the reference "Comparative Rail Safety"
Comparative Rail Safety blog post by Alon Levy shows explicit numbers about the fatalities from Wikipedia's List of rail accidents and List of countries by rail usage. The question is not about whether the author correctly collected the data from these Wikipedia articles, but about whether the overall conclusion about comparative safety of the US passenger rail is correct. There can be multiple reasons to doubt that this is the correct data to make such conclusion:

List of rail accidents may only list notable accidents and, in particular, may not list the majority of pedestrian fatalities caused by a contact with passenger train. It also may omit other less notable accidents.
List of rail accidents is an English-language Wikipedia page, and its coverage of accidents in non-English-speaking countries may be less comprehensive than that of the U.S. (i.e., it may list a larger proportion of accidents in the U.S. than in Japan).


Here are some references and information I found to fact check this statement myself.

According to Wikipedia, Japan had 446.7B passenger-km in 2019 while the US had 32.5B passenger-km. Wikipedia refers to the "Transport - Passenger transport" table in OECD Data. Looking at the OECD data directly, it seems that the number of annual passenger-km in Japan is about 13.4..15.3 times larger than that in the US. E.g. if I use the table "Passenger transport" (quarterly) for the last 4 quarters for which the data is available for both countries (2022'Q4..2023'Q3), I get a ratio of 378 / 24.8 = 15.2. It should be noted, however, that the table comes with a warning "Although there are clear definitions for all the terms used in this survey, caution is required when comparing data between countries." Also, they state that the unit is "passenger-km" while it appears to be "million passenger-km".
JR East's "Comparison of Safety Between Japan and EU Railways" states that in 2013 there were 274 total fatalities (when discussing railway operational accidents in Japan). It also states "The annual average number of fatalities in accidents related to railways in the latest five years is 311 persons, likely evoking a social demand on Japanese railways for further improvement of safety." perhaps referring to the period 2009--2013 given that it was published in 2014.
The Journalist's Resource "Transportation safety over time: Cars, planes, trains, walking, cycling" states that in 2000-2009 the number of average annual fatalities in the US were 38 for railroads 25 for rail transit.

These numbers do not appear to support the stated Japan rail safety claim. For example, combining the data from #1 and #2 we may conclude that Japan had one death per 1.49B passenger-km in 2013 (R = 1 / 1.49 = 0.67 where 1.49 = 408.7 / 274), while combining #1 and #3 we may conclude that the US had R = 6.9 or 4.1 depending on whether "rail transit fatalities" are included or excluded from the numerator. However, it is not clear to me whether this is the correct computation. In particular, (1) OECD passenger-km metric for the US jumps by a factor of 3 between 2013'Q4 and 2014'Q1, which seems suspicious; (2) it is not clear whether OECD US passenger-km includes rail transit or not, hence not clear whether it should be included in the numerator; (3) OECD data has explicit warning for being careful when comparing it between countries; (4) both fatality data points are more than 10 years old, and come from difference periods (one might hope that safety improves over time in both countries).

Welcome to Skeptics! I am nervous that you have specified the metric you think is relevant. What is relevant is what the claimant meant. In particular, the claimant's use of Wikipedia's list of accidents (which only includes notable ones) means that they are not including the daily deaths of pedestrians (including those deliberately taking their own lives).

e.g. compare the claimant's quoted "159 deaths over 20 years" to Wikipedia's "Pedestrian railroad accidents are the leading cause of death on railways. More than 7,200 pedestrians have been killed by trains in the United States since 1997."

If you are going to look at the number of rail related deaths per passenger km, than the US is always going to be at a disadvantage, because rail there is dominated by goods traffic (i.e. passengers per train is low). Hence, I'm not sure your R is a very useful indicator. Passenger deaths per passenger-km is more reasonable (and for that indicator the claim appears true).

The data see shows the US at 32.5 per billion passenger km while Japan is at 446.7 and China is at 1,550 which means the same number of issues is going to make the US look much worse. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_rail_usage

@Oddthinking Focusing on "Comparative Rail Safety", both the title and the statement "The US turns out to be the least safe among ..." imply a conclusion about safety of (passenger) rail transport, which is what I'm questioning. I.e. I'm not questioning that the author correctly loaded the data from Wikipedia, but rather questioning the conclusion, i.e. whether this data is representative of the overall safety of passenger rail in the US as compared to Japan. 7200 figure is the # of fatalities from all rail accidents, not just passenger rail accidents. Will update the question.

@TimRias Trains primarily focusing on goods traffic are explicitly excluded by only considering passenger train accidents. Indeed, there can be two meaning of safety: how safe is it to be on a train as a passenger, and how safe is the operation of passenger trains (per utility delivered). The question is about the latter, and hence should include pedestrian fatalities. The former would also be a valid but distinct question.

I think your 3 and 4th bullet point together make this almost impossible to answer because that would be a number that is likely not tracked by anyone. If a person dies as a pedestrian (or in a car) in a train collision it is usually irrelevant whether the train carried passengers or freight so I doubt these two would be separated.


Using 2014 data the fatality rate for US long-haul rail service is 0.43  per BPMT (1 death per 2.32B miles traveled); excluding non-passenger deaths brings that to 0.15 per BPMT (1 passenger death per 6.66B miles traveled).
Japan, meanwhile, has the Shinkansen aka 'Bullet Train' which claims a 50-year, no fatalities service record.  That, by itself, gets Japan's numbers
well beyond the US since the Shinkansen routinely logs north of 70 billion passenger km traveled per year. The remainder of their train service would have to be a meat grinder for the US stats to have any hope of catching up.
Keep in mind, the Shinkansen is a source of national pride for Japan, and it's safety record is a matter of prestige worldwide. The US rail system, meanwhile, is more vestigial than anything, and struggles to receive support against the backdrop of the Federal Interstate System.
So the comparison is akin to some guy you interviewed at a bar about his weightlifting routine and then comparing it to an Olympic athlete.
